# What component would go Here in the image below

Tags: pcb

[image: it is a dsl splitter and filter]

please can anyone tell me what component goes into the PCB? it is from a DSL filter

Comment: An inductor. The **L** gives it away. Can't say what value though.

Comment: A common mode choke more than likely.

Comment: Probably a two winding inductor. Probably arranged so that it provides a low pass path from phone-line to telephone connection so that the phone does not load down the high frequency DSL signals.

Comment: @Andyaka Your comment is shorter. The alternative was 'very much shorter'.